# Why are these 2 structs with the same contents not layout compatible types for Clang, and vector doesn't work for MSVC

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Update: Just updated MSVC compiler to 17.4.5.
MSVC now says that `A` and `Az` are compatible types in Release mode but not in Debug mode when `std::vector` is included in the structs. Really weird. May be related to the size difference of vectors. Vectors in Release mode consist of the expected 3 pointers. In debug mode it's expanded by an additional pointer which appears to be added in for some sort of additional use verification.

According to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#general-11) description of layout compatible types, struct A and struct Az should qualify as the struct contents are identical.

> Two types cv1 T1 and cv2 T2 are layout-compatible types if T1 and T2 are the same type, layout-compatible enumerations, or layout-compatible standard-layout class types.

Clang fails to compile as `std::is_layout_compatible` isn't implemented. With both `vector` and `int`, gcc works and returns true for `is_layout_compatible` while MSVC returns true in Release mode but false in Debug mode.

[compiler explorer int and vector](https://godbolt.org/z/KzG5vMsab)
[compiler explorer int only](https://godbolt.org/z/vv5vcMda1)

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

struct Az {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int i;
};

struct A {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof:" << sizeof(A) << " Layout_compatible:" << std::is_layout_compatible_v<A, Az> << '\n';
}


MSVC 2022 Output Debug mode:
sizeof:40 Layout_compatible:0

MSVC 2022 Output Release mode:
sizeof:32 Layout_compatible:1
```

Comment: @Eljay `std::is_layout_compatible` has two arguments. If it only applied if T1 and T2 were identical one would just use `std::is_same`

Comment: "Two types cv1 T1 and cv2 T2 are layout-compatible types if T1 and T2 are the same type, layout-compatible enumerations, or layout-compatible standard-layout class types."  They are not the same type.  They are not layout-compatible enumerations.  They are not standard-layout.

Comment: @doug MSVC in your first compiler explorer link fails only because of some compiler explorer related issue. Modify the source a bit and it will compile. Clang is failing because it doesn't find `is_layout_compatible_v`. Presumably they haven't implemented it yet (it requires specific compiler support).

Comment: In the version with only `int` members the classes are layout-compatible. In the version with `std::vector` it is unspecified, because `std::vector` may or may not be standard-layout.

Comment: @user17732522 Well, this is interesting. Just updated MSVC and in debug it's not layout compatible but in release it is.  So it really is "may be"! Investigating.